# Python wrong calculation with np.uint8

Tags: python, numpy

While trying to do some calculations in a Jupyter notebook. I tried to raise an array to the power of `2`, either using `**` or using `np.power`. Both yield the wrong results.

[image]

What might be the problem?
If I run on a single number the calculation is correct.

Comment: Use a longer data type.

Comment: Please copy and paste the text instead of uploading a screenshot.

Comment: All your values are constrained to fit in one byte (dtype=uint8). 62**2 becomes 4 if you try and put it in one byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the data type of your array is `uint8` which can only store 8-bit numbers i.e., 0-255. After that, overflow happens and your results get wrapped around which gives you `x mod 256` as representation for `x`. For example, `62*62=3844` but since 3844 can't be accommodated in 8-bits, you get the result, 4 which is `3844 mod 256`. So to get the correct result, you need to change your data type to a longer one e.g., `int`. Try this:

```
image.astype(np.int)**2
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is of type uint-8, which is an 8-bit integer. The calculation is fine - what you're seeing is an overflow.

For example:

```
np.uint8(20) * np.uint8(20)
```

output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: RuntimeWarning:

overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars

144
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of background.

When you say:

> If i run on a single number- calculation is correct

What you probably mean is that you are using the python builtin `int` type. The `int` in Python is arbitrary precision, meaning that as many bytes of storage as are necessary will be allocated in order to hold the data item without overflow.

When you are using NumPy arrays, this is not the case, because they are implemented as a sequence of values that are stored adjacent and regularly spaced in memory -- you could not make one of the values require more bytes because is nowhere for it to "grow".  So each NumPy array has an associated data type that is used when the array is created, and all values in it have this data type.

When an operation is performed using NumPy arrays, the length of the output data type is based on the data type in the inputs.  Because your array `image` is of datatype `np.uint8`, (and the `2` is a value that can be stored in a `np.uint8`), the result of the operation `image ** 2` is also of datatype `np.uint8`, so the values overflow because they exceed 2^8.

If you do instead:

```
image.astype(np.uint16) ** 2
```

this will operate using a temporary copy of your input data with datatype `np.uint16`, so the output will be of datatype `np.uint16`, and this will be sufficient to store the precision that you need.